# How to restore in-App purchases with Parse?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, in-app-purchase

I would like to create a "Restore in-App" button because it is required by Apple. I am using Parse for my iAP product and I used this code to do that:

```
PFPurchase.buyProduct("iapbanner", block: { (error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Errore", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                self.opzioniTableView.reloadData()
            }
        })
```

This works fine. Though, in the Parse's documentation it's not mentioned how to restore your iAp so I'm asking you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `PFPurchase.restore()` to restore purchases with Parse. I'm not sure why they don't have this in their docs.